# getting incorrect answer. what is wrong with this code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
x=raw_input('what is your favorite number? ')
n=x*10
print n
```

If I plug in 5, I don't get 50. I get 5555555

I have tried declaring float(n) and tooling around with it. nothing helped. I realize this is minor league, but I am just starting to teach myself python.
Thanks, Todd

Answer (score 1):

You are taking in your number as `raw_input`, meaning, it is returned to the program as a string. When you multiply a string by an integer and print the result, it just prints the string `x` times, in your case 10 because you attempted to multiply by 10. To prove this, change, the 10 to 20 and watch what happens.

There are two ways to fix this. The first would be to use `input()` instead of `raw_input()`, so that it returns a number as a result.

```
x=input("Please enter a number here.\n")
```

The second way would be to reassign `x` to the integer equivalent of the string, using the function `int()`.

```
x=int(x) # Will turn "10", which is what you have, into 10
```

This should solve your problem.

Best of luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the default data type of [raw_input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) is [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html). You have to cast the string input to an integer for achieving the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

When you read a value in from user input like this it is as a string.  So x actually equals the string '5' but what you actually want is the number 5.

```
int(x) * 10
```